# C# Interop define an array of Worksheets

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vsto

How can I define an array with 4 `worksheets`?

For example these are my `worksheets`:

```
    var wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    var wsEvars = wb.Sheets["Evars"];
    var wsProps = wb.Sheets["Props"];
    var wsEvents = wb.Sheets["Events"];
    var wsListVars = wb.Sheets["List Vars"];
```

And I want to include them in an array as follows:

```
var sheets = [wsEvars, wsProps, wsEvents, wsListVars];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these references...

```
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.Linq;
using Worksheet = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

If you only need com objects you can do...

```
var wsEvars = wb.Sheets["Evars"];
var wsProps = wb.Sheets["Props"];
var wsEvents = wb.Sheets["Events"];
var wsListVars = wb.Sheets["List Vars"];

var sheets = new Excel.Worksheet[] {wsEvars, wsProps, wsEvents, wsListVars};
```

If you need the VSTO host interface...

```
var _factory = Globals.Factory;    

var wsEvars = _factory.GetVstoObject(wb.Sheets["Evars"]);
    var wsProps = _factory.GetVstoObject(wb.Sheets["Props"]);
    var wsEvents = _factory.GetVstoObject(wb.Sheets["Events"]);
    var wsListVars = _factory.GetVstoObject(wb.Sheets["List Vars"]);

    var sheets = new Worksheet[] {wsEvars, wsProps, wsEvents, wsListVars};
```

Or with linq...

```
var _sheetsArray = new[]{"wsEvars", "wsProps", "wsEvents", "wsListVars"}.Join(
    _wb.Worksheets.Cast<Excel.Worksheet>(), // outer  
    name => name, s => s.Name,              // key accessors
    (tag, s) => _factory.GetVstoObject(s)   // output selector
).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare and initialize an array as follows:

`var sheets = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets[] { wsEvars, wsProps, wsEvents, wsListVars };`

Comment: This returns: `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).`

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets` is an interface for a collection, not for single sheets so that would be an array of collections right?